# Flutter bottom modal not immediately updated

Tags: flutter

After achieve the button outline change outline color based on click button,everything working fine.

The issues comes when i'm using this three button inside bottom modal. For example i choose one of three button ,it should have outline color apply to that particular button. I can see it apply when i dismiss the modal and reopen back.

Sometimes i need to hold longer button press and moving a bit can see the effect. Its a bug or i'm doing wrong.

Add the GIF for your view.When choose button it not update immediately need to dismiss and open back to see changes

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final String testImg = "https://thumblr.uniid.it/product/171331/a9d8d2f96f33.jpg";


  int _isSelected;


  List<String> listS = [
    "X",
    "S",
    "M",
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("My"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text("TEST MODAL click button below"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: new BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: new FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: (){
                  _showBuy();
            },
            icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: new Text("ADD TO CART",
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBuy(){
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext contex){
      return new Scaffold(
        body:new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listS.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return new OutlineButton(
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                  ),
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                      width: 2.0,
                      color: ((_isSelected == index) ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                    setState((){
                      _isSelected = index;
                      });
                    },
                  child: new Text(listS[index]),
                );
              },
          ),
      );
    });
  }


}
```

Full code and sorry for design just for testing.Thanks in advance.GIF below.

[enter link description here](https://i.imgflip.com/27kwgp.gif)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking or what the problem is - please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the method setState does two things:
1) Call the function you passed to it
2) Call the `build` method of the widget (a very simplified way to think about it)

You can then ask yourself, does calling the `build` method cause the widget being passed to showModalBottomSheet be repainted? The answer is no, because, in your code, the building of the widget comes from the method `_showBuy`, which has to be triggered by a press of the button.

The solution is to create a Stateful widget and pass it to `showModalBottomSheet`, and move the state management to that widget. By doing so, you will call the `setState` of this new Stateful widget instead of _MyHomePageState, and that will work as expected. (You can use callbacks to pass the state back to `_MyHomePageState` if you want).

Comment: Is there are way to create a `StatefulWidget` which renders (via the Build method) the `showModalBottomSheet`? I've actually found this problem quite tricky as my first instinct was to create a separate `StatefulWidget` as you have proposed, since the `showModalBottomSheet` was a function, I couldn't figure out a graceful way to migrate the whole ModalBottomSheet in to its on stateful widget class. Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: You need to define a StatefulWidget that manages the user interaction and other state management, then uses the showModalBottomSheet method to show that widget. It does not matter where you call showModalBottomSheet from (whether a StatefulWidget or not).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the modal in a `StatefulBuilder` widget. Wrapping it in a `StatefulBuilder` will instantly create a context and a separate stateSetter to manually trigger a rebuild and update the modal [more information on StatefulBuilder here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)